# How to resize a JFrame so that the components also expand or reduce in size, depending on user?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resize, jframe

I will explain my point using the pictures below:

this example the project is executed:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/s1nLH.png]

As you see the user re size's the frame, which then does not expand the components itself but instead fills it with a grey color:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdNA3.png]

I would like to know how to re size the JFrame making the components within
   the frame expand or reduce in size depending on the user.

Here is the main class of this program, I am using GridBag layout and before someone points out I do understand the setSize function can be overridden by the managers, Only realized after coding this program.

Please note this is in fact for a project and this is just another previous program I have used, I would just like to know how to go about it.

```
public class Email{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // The GUI thread is created, with the JFrame in the run method
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

             public void run(){

                JFrame frame = new Compose("Send an Email");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(700 , 600);
                // This stops the program from being resized
                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: use flowLayout in your design are you coding the design or building from the IDE

Comment: I am not using a GUI builder or any of that,coding from hand. Using flowLayout  wont be ideal for my program either, besides if I do maximize the screen, it will only add them to the first row not adjust the size accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are using the `GridBagLayout`. So you need to modify your constraints to get your desired effect.

Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

In particular you need to look at the weightx/weighty contraints. This tells the layout how to allocate space as the frame size changes. Because your values are 0, none of the components resize and the components are displayed in the center. I would guess you want the text field to resize.

So read the tutorial, download the demo code and play with it. Then modify your layout to do what you want.

Comment: Right so my content pane is using a border layout with my other panels using a few other different layouts, how would I go about doing it then?

Comment: Read the tutorial. It explains how ALL the layout managers work.  That is why I pointed you to the tutorial. You learn the basics of each layout manager first. You nest your panels and use appropriate layout managers. Based on the pictures you posted is looks like you are using a GridBagLayout so that is why I suggested you start there. Based on the picture I suggest you can do it easily with the GridBagLayout. I have no idea what other layouts you may be using so I obviously can't comment on what you are doing because I'm not a mind reader.

Comment: You ain't a mind reader, but as I have already said I am using border layout for my other program and wanted something specific to that.

Comment: Good luck I can't help since your requirement makes no sense.  A BorderLayout is not for displaying 10 individual components.

Comment: No, the BorderLayout is used in the content pane to display all the JPanels on the sides stated. So I could have various JPanels, which would have different components in them, like one for a menu bar, the other panel, to keep two things like a buffer image and textfield together etc.

Comment: @MedicoreProgrammer, I know what a BorderLayout is. The suggestion is to create a panel with your components. Use a GridBagLayout and an add your components to the panel. Then you add this panel to the CENTER of the BorderLayout of the frame.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;


public class emailjava extends JFrame{

    public emailjava(){
    adjustFrame();
    }




    /**
     * variable declaration
     **/
    private final javax.swing.JLabel bccLbl= new javax.swing.JLabel();
    private final javax.swing.JTextField bccText= new javax.swing.JTextField();
    private final javax.swing.JTextField ccTExt= new javax.swing.JTextField();
    private final javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1= new javax.swing.JLabel();
    private final javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2= new javax.swing.JLabel();
    private final javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    private final javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
    private final javax.swing.JLabel messageLbl= new javax.swing.JLabel();
    private final javax.swing.JTextArea messageText = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
    private final javax.swing.JLabel subjectLbl= new javax.swing.JLabel();
    private final javax.swing.JTextField subjectText= new javax.swing.JTextField();
    private final javax.swing.JTextField toText= new javax.swing.JTextField();
    //emd of the declaration

   public final void adjustFrame(){

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


        JLabel []array = {jLabel1,jLabel2,bccLbl,subjectLbl,messageLbl};
        for (JLabel jLabel : array) {
           jLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        }

        jLabel1.setText("To :");
        jLabel2.setText("CC :");
        bccLbl.setText("BCC :");
        subjectLbl.setText("SubjectLine");
        messageLbl.setText("MessageBody");

        messageText.setColumns(20);
        messageText.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(messageText);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(messageLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 77, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(subjectLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(bccLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(5, 5, 5)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(toText)
                    .addComponent(ccTExt)
                    .addComponent(bccText)
                    .addComponent(subjectText)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 391, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(toText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(ccTExt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(bccText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(bccLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(subjectText, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(subjectLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 295, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(messageLbl, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 29, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new emailjava().setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

this is the code that i came up with tried it my self and it is working 100%

Comment: Thank you, for your time I will have a look at this.